# What is best tool to use for editing text on auto-insurance cards?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, corel-paint-shop-pro

I actually had easier time with Ms paint than trying to figure out the layers on photoshop. The scanned image of the insurance card has impregnated 'VOID' images in the background that are not in the original as a fraud prevention measure.  If I scan in a photo copy of the original, the 'VOID' are not there.

I don't need to actually figure out the font to type the text. Just copying and pasting text from one part of the insurance card to the other. Also need to mask any background mismatches due to the copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

Select the text using a lasso (marquee) or pen tool, copy it, paste it to a new layer, move it where you need it, then touch up the edges using a soft brush either as an eraser or by making a layer mask.